# Spring Data JPA - saving a new entity with custom id / primary key

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In short, my question is how to save an entity with preset primary key(instead of null) using Spring data JPA.

To explain, consider a simple entity class named `Customer`. Remember, id is not set to auto increment, and it must be a custom unique value. This is a small example only. I need the id in my actual table to be a custom unique one, something like username.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cust_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer custId;

    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 30)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 30)
    private String lastName;

    //getter, setters 
}
```

And, I have a `CustomerRepository` as

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
}
```

Now, I suppose I have to insert a new customer record with id 101. The expected way is:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setCustId(101);
customer.setFirstName("Some");
customer.setLastName("Name");

repository.save(customer);
```

But, it happens that `repository.save()` doesn't insert the new customer with id 101. So, how should I do this?

Comment: What does it do instead? What is saved to the database? What is your test to ensure it is not saved?

Comment: @user1888440 Nothing get saved to the database. I checked the database table manually to ensure this.

Comment: Sounds like your transaction didn't commit. Are you using @Transactional? Make sure you check the DB after the transaction commits or make sure flush is called.

Comment: @user1888440 Thanks bro! It works after calling `flush()`.

Comment: De nada, I'm adding the comment as an answer so you can mark it answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are in an active transaction always remember to call flush explicitly or to ensure the transaction has committed before independently checking the database to ensure changes have been made.

Comment: There is also handy `saveAndFlush()` method.